# Cannot run/import pip installed python packages, using Ubuntu 17.04 VirtualBox VM

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, ipython

I'm usingUbuntu 17.04 VM via Virtual box. Python work. I ran `sudo apt-get install pip`, and it worked. I have used pip to install ipython and numpy, and it was successful. I can import numpy in a python shell. But, i cannot open ipython. For example:

```
$ ipython
```

gives "The program `ipython` is not currently installed"

Maybe this is a path problem?

I ran 
    `pip show ipython` 
and it gives a path that appears in the list when I run `python -m site`. 
I think this means it should find ipython command?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your `.bashrc` and add the ipython path (showed with command `pip show ipython`), like this:

```
$ nano ~/.bashrc
# added for run ipython
export PATH="/home/user/path/ipython/bin:$PATH"
```

After this, close terminal and reopen.

Sugestion:
For a level up in package management, try to install [anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download/).

Comment: i tried this but it fails. `echo $PATH` now shows the path given by `pip show ipython` at the front of the list, but i get the same error ("ipython is not currently installed"

Comment: Did you try to call ipython through the path shown with command `whereis ipython`?

Comment: `whereis ipython` gives "ipython:"

Comment: There is something wrong. This command should show the path of the application. What is returned, if you do `whereis jupyter`?

Comment: same, just `jupyter:` is returned

Comment: I needed to keep progressing so i broke down: I went ahead and took the "cheap" way out-- `sudo apt install ipython` . it works, but i think the pip install should have worked

Comment: hmm, noted. I'm prototyping for a memory- and disk-limited device. So i wanted to get only bare-bones necessary stuff on there. Ipython will come off after some development. thanks for the help

Comment: Conda/Anacond is just for development, for minimal installation (45.2 MB), [see miniconda.](https://conda.io/miniconda.html) U're welcome. :-)